# Petersson formula with powers

Tags: number-theory, automorphic-forms

The classical Petersson formula gives a formula for
$$\sum_{c>0} \frac{S(m, n, c)}{c} J(m, n, c)$$
for $J$ an explicit Bessel function. Is there a similar formula existing for different weights or functions, for instance
$$\sum_{c>0} \frac{S(m, n, c)}{c^k} J(m, n, c)$$
for integers (or real numbers) $k$?

Comment: For some reason, there are votes to close on this question (I imagine by people who don't work in the field of automorphic forms, which is what this question is about). In any case, the short answer is no, since the Petersson formula specifically is proven by taking the inner product of two Poincare series and computing this inner product in two different ways, and it gives you exactly this expression in terms of Bessel functions and Kloosterman sums.

Comment: The long answer is that you can work with more general Poincare series than those used in the proof of the Petersson trace formula, and you will get more complicated expansions in terms of automorphic forms; not only will this involve holomorphic cusp forms, it also involves Maass forms and real analytic Eisenstein series.

Comment: A good place to start on this is Chapters 15 and 16 of Iwaniec-Kowalski.